# scale() and shape() in Processing

Tags: java, processing, scale

**UPDATE:** I think I figured it out. The scaleMultiplier also applied to the translate that I was trying to do. I had a suspicion this was the case but couldn't figure out exactly how it got affected.

Anyone familiar with a spinoff of Java called Processing? I'm trying to do something simple, scale a shape and place it in the center of the sketch. This is my code in a nutshell:

```
pushMatrix();

float scaleX, scaleY, scaleMultiplier, resetX, resetY, transX, transY;

scaleX = 500 / (float)clickState.bounds.getWidth();
scaleY = 500 / (float)clickState.bounds.getHeight();
scaleMultiplier = min(scaleX,scaleY);
resetX = -(float)clickState.bounds.getX();
resetY = -(float)clickState.bounds.getY();

transX = resetX + ((800 - ((float)clickState.bounds.getWidth() * scaleMultiplier))/2);
transY = resetY + ((550 - ((float)clickState.bounds.getHeight() * scaleMultiplier))/2);

scale(scaleMultiplier);
shape(clickState.pshape, transX, transY);

popMatrix();
```

What I'm trying to do is scale a state on a US Map. clickState is the state that the user clicked on. clickState.bounds is a Rectangle that surrounds the shape of the state. getX() and getY() return the x and y coords of the upper left hand corner of said box. I want to scale the state so that it's no bigger than 500x500 pixels. After that, I want to translate it so that it's in the middle of the sketch, which is 800x550.

Here's where I run into trouble: When I do

```
shape(clickState.pshape, resetX, resetY);
```

It draws the state in the upper left hand corner of the sketch. That's exactly what it should do. Then from there I want to add the number of pixels that it would take to center the shape, which is what transX and transY are for. However, when I use transX and transY, the shape gets drawn almost completely off the canvas, depending on where the state is located (even if its only being moved 50 pixels to the right from 0,0). It doesn't make any sense to me whatsoever. I've tried all sorts of combinations of translate(), and even skipping scale() altogether and using a width and height in shape(). It's like Processing is trying to frustrate me on purpose. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the processing IDE and if you could post your entire code, it would be easier for me to try and edit and run.

Comment: I would need to send you a whole zip file since I'm using a library plus the svg of the map, and also the data that I'm trying to display on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `Processing`, but matrix operations are *not* commutative—the order matters. Typically, operations are applied in an apparent *last-specified-first-applied* order, as shown in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon).

Answer (score 0):

Vince, I think I was trying to do something very similar last week. Sounds like you figured it out, but check out the answers on this board:

http://forum.processing.org/topic/how-do-i-move-svg-child-shapes#25080000000689051